# É possível nomear um módulo de python usando a função __import__

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte código

`__import__('some_module')`

E eu queria saber se era possível fazer uma coisa deste género:

`__import__('some_module') as some_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como tens na pergunta não é, mas podes atribuir o retorno de `__import__` a uma var, ex:

```
mod_alias = __import__('string')
```

O equivalente a:

```
import string as mod_alias
```

Neste caso `mod_alias` é o teu alias.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/MuffledDroopyAfricanelephant)