# Python import arquivo a partir de variável

Tags: python, python-3.x, diretório, import

Se eu definir uma variável como o diretório do qual eu importarei um arquivo, tal como:

`a = 'C:\\Users\\Windows 7\\Desktop\\Program10.py`

Se eu tentar `from a import foo`, me é dado ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'.

Em contexto, a variável é definida como diretório neste loop:

```
d_user = getpass.getuser()
diret = "C:\\Users\\" + d_user
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(diret):
    if lookfor in files:
        a = join(root, lookfor)
        break
```

E o que quero fazer é `from a import func`ou `from a import variab`

Comment: Será que isso resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272043/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-nomear-um-m%C3%B3dulo-de-python-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-import/272045#272045

Comment: Acredito que é porque a variável não é considerada no PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso aqui:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(a)
```

Os módulos são procurados nesta ordem:

- Diretório atual
- Variável de ambiente `PYTHONPATH`
- Endereço default de instalação

Use este link como referência (em inglês): [Caminho de procura de módulos em Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

*Edit:*
Após prestar atenção no seu código, acredito que `from a import foo()` **não** funcionaria, remove os parênteses.

Comment: Tudo bem, porém como posso importar o 'a' após executar esses dois comandos?

Comment: Como já estava fazendo ;)
Bota eles antes.

Comment: Importei sys e defini sys.path.append(a). Ao tentar importar 'a' ou importar um elemento de 'a' o erro foi mesmo: Módulo não encontrado. 
 https://imgur.com/a/PituS